# How to serialize user defined objects to WriteEvent?

Tags: c#, etw, etw-eventsource

From MSDN documentation, Write-event supports only int and string param types. I want to pass a user-created ct to Write-event, how to get this functionality? What would be the right serializer to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Xml, Json, custom, etc. The right serializer depends on what you intend to do with the data when its written out, and how you intend to read it (human or code).

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

- Use [the new .NET 4.6 feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vancem/rich-payload-data-in-eventsource-v4-6) as magicandre1981 suggested. And that is the preferable option unless you have to use .NET 4.5, 4.0 or even 3.5.
- Manually serialize them in JSON or Bond or etc
- Manually create the `EventData` struct and pass to [`WriteEventCore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource.writeeventcore%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (has to be inside `unsafe`) - [TPL](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TPLETWProvider.cs,65efc3372293bdaf) currently uses this method.
- Or you could [this](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/Tx/blob/master/Samples/BondEtw/Readme.md) for example. There is [a blog post](http://sergeysharp.com/blog/2015/09/28/welcome-to-binary-in-etw/) about that.

Comment: FWIW, Jon Wagner has an [interesting take](https://github.com/jonwagner/EventSourceProxy) on creating/generating EventSource

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10 (also backported to Win7/8.1) there is support for [Rich Payload Data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2015/09/20/rich-payload-data-in-eventsource-v4-6.aspx) since .Net 4.6:

```
// define a ‘plain old data’ class 
    [EventData]
    class SimpleData {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Address { get; set; }
    }

    [EventSource(Name = "Samples-EventSourceDemos-RuntimeDemo")]
    public sealed class RuntimeDemoEventSource : EventSource
    {
        // define the singleton instance of the event source
        public static RuntimeDemoEventSource Log = new RuntimeDemoEventSource();

        // Rich payloads only work when the self-describing format 
        private RuntimeDemoEventSource() : base(EventSourceSettings.EtwSelfDescribingEventFormat) { }

        // define a new event. 
        public void LogSimpleData(string message, SimpleData data) { WriteEvent(1, message, data); }
    }

RuntimeDemoEventSource.Log.LogSimpleData(
        "testMessage", 
        new SimpleData() { Name = "aName", Address = 234 });
```

Read the blog and document for more details.

Comment: Rich Payload Data cannot be passed to WriteEvent method. It needs to be passed to "public void Write<T>(string eventName, T data);" method of EventSource. Else I am missing something.